# PowerShell Add 1 day to the AccountExpire attribute of an AD user 

Tags: powershell, active-directory

As topic states. How can I put 1 extra day to the selected user account.

I know AD goes by Windows File Time. Does anyone know the easiest and least code written method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can modify the `accountExpires` property of an AD user through the [Set-ADUser](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617215.aspx) cmdlet [included in Windows Server 2008 R2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378937%28v=ws.10%29.aspx):

```
Import-Module activedirectory

$expireDate = (Get-ADUser -Identity "John Appleseed" -Properties accountExpires).accountExpires
$renewedExpireDate = ([System.DateTime]::FromFileTime($expireDate)).AddDays(1)

Set-ADUser -Identity "John Appleseed" -AccountExpirationDate $renewedExpireDate
```

As you said, the value of the [accountExpires](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675098%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property is represented as a [Windows file time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which is a 64-bit integer. In this example we convert it to a [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) to easily modify it and then pass it to the `-AccountExpirationDate` parameter to update the user.

Comment: It works if you replace by $expireDate by $expireDate.accountExpires in FromFileTime method. $expireDate is an ADUser not a DateTime. Can you change ?

Comment: @JPBlanc I corrected the sample code. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Quest AD module](http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx):

```
Set-qaduser <username> -AccountExpires ( [datetime]( get-qaduser <username> -IncludeAllProperties ).AccountExpires ).AddDays(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also be accomplished in a multi domain environment by adding the -server switch and passing in the domain string (i.e. "domain.corp.root").  I also had to move the .accountExpires as it was in the wrong place in this code sample. Thanks for providing this, it was exactly what I needed.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$expireDate = (Get-ADUser -Identity "samaccountname" -Properties accountExpires -server "domain.corp.root")

$renewedExpireDate = ([System.DateTime]::FromFileTime($expireDate.accountExpires)).AddDays(1)

Set-ADUser -Identity "samaccountname" -AccountExpirationDate $renewedExpireDate -server "domain.corp.root"
```